# Setting Variable with VBS to output in Batch

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, vbscript, environment-variables

I have a VBSript that outputs a string. Could I set that string as a environment variable?.

Example: Say my script creates the string: abcstring . Well I want to add string output as the  variable: StringVar

So if I enter %StringVar% in a batch command it will output: abcstring

Is this possible?

Comment: I should add, the use for the VBSript is to extract parts two other strings and add them into one string.

Comment: Do you run the VBScript from the batch script and want the output available in a variable in that (parent) batch script? Or do you run the VBScript and then at some later point start a batch script where you want to use the output of the VBScript?

Answer (score 1):

If you create it as `Volatile`, it will be available after your VBScript terminates (actually, until the user logs off).

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Environment("VOLATILE")("StringVar") = "This is a string"
End With
```